# IE7 activeX control eating keypresses

Tags: internet-explorer-7, activex

We have an IE7 webbrowser activeX control for displaying our help system.

With generic content the site works in IE8 with the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` tag added.

However running in the activeX control it no longer responds to keypresses (tabs, spaces, 0-9a-z, etc).

To check that the keypresses were working I added some javascript to fire up the keypress as alerts.  This works as expected in IE8->7 but no response in IE7 control so something is preventing the keypresses getting to the container.

Any ideas as to why IE7 ActiveX control may be eating/not responding to the keypresses?

Comment: Why exactly are you worried about IE7 support?

Comment: Because the help system is HTML running in an activex control and the lowest system we support is WinXP running IE7.  I didn't make this decision, I'd much prefer not to use HTML for the help.